# Why won't this code segment produce a result?

Tags: java, eclipse

I need to fix this block of code in java, I am using eclipse

```
(total == MAX)
if (total < sum)
        System.out.println("total == MAX and < sum.");
else
System.out.println("total is not equal to MAX");
```

so i made my adjustments and got this

```
package lecture1_1;

public class Total {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int MAX = 100;
        int total = 50;
        int sum = 150;
        if (total == MAX)
            if (total < sum)
                System.out.println("total is equal to MAX and less than sum.");
        else
        System.out.println("total is not equal to MAX");

    }
    

}
```

but it prints no result. what am i missing?

Comment: have you tried using the debugger in eclipse to step through your code and see what is happening ?

Answer (score 2):

TL;DR use brackets to establish code block boundaries - it will make code more readable.

What you're expecting is this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int MAX = 100;
    int total = 50;
    int sum = 150;
    if (total == MAX) {
        if (total < sum) {
            System.out.println("total is equal to MAX and less than sum.");
        }
    }
    else {
       System.out.println("total is not equal to MAX");
    }
}
```

But what you have is this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int MAX = 100;
    int total = 50;
    int sum = 150;
    if (total == MAX) {
        if (total < sum) {
            System.out.println("total is equal to MAX and less than sum.");
        }
        else {
           System.out.println("total is not equal to MAX");
        }
    }
}
```